# Spring.NET Creation of Object with Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, spring, spring.net

I have an object with two parameters that needs to be created via Spring.NET using the configuration file for decoupling.

```
public Object(string param1, string param2) { ... }
```

The two parameters are dynamically passed in based on user interaction where they pass in a username and password, so these values can't be hard coded to the configuration file. Therefore the following will not work:

```xml
<object name="WinFormApplicationWorkflow" type="COM.Us.Workflow.ApplicationWorkflow, "COM.Us.Workflow ">
<!-- this will NOT work -->
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="TESTUSER"></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg index="1" value="TESTPW"></constructor-arg>
  <!-- / -->        
  <property name="NetworkWorkflow" ref="NetworkWorkflow" />
  <property name="ExceptionLogger" ref="ExceptionLogger" />
</object>
```

How can I do this with Spring.NET, so that I can just do:

```
ContextRegister.GetContext().GetObject("WinFormApplicationWorkflow");
```

But still pass in the two necessary parameters to my workflow class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overloaded method GetObject(string, object[]) of the *Spring.Objects.Factory.IObjectFactory* interface to pass in your dynamic values for object creation.

```
string userName = "Test";
string password = "Test";
object[] arguments = new object[] { userName, password };

ContextRegister.GetContext().GetObject("WinFormApplicationWorkflow", arguments);
```

Comment: Now this is interesting. Docs say this method can return shared or independent instance. But I see no way it can be a singleton, because you may pass different constructor arguments. Does it mean you will always get a new object? Or you singleton will get reconfigured (sounds bad)? Or you will get separate instances per unique arguments?

Comment: @Alexander : In my opinion, each GetObject() call will create a new instance of the specified type, calling the constructor that matches the given arguments.